# Updating Integer on the Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating something which shows a list of cats and then increments a counter when the image is clicked. I've got everything working so when the image is clicked it increments the integer when I log it to the console. The only problem is that on the page the counter doesn't increment, it stays static at zero.

Here is my code. I've tried to create an update function which takes everything with the class tag and then loops through it replacing the HTML with the same thing so it redraws the text.

However it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

```
var HTMLcatName = '<h1>%data%</h1>';
var HTMLcatImage = '<img id="cat" src="%data%">';
var HTMLcatCounter = '<p class="counter">Number of clicks: %data%</p>';
var noCats = 'No cats selected m8';

var cats = {

    "name": ["Monte", "Jib"],
    "image": ["images/monte.jpg", "images/jib.jpg"],
    "clicks": [0, 0],

    display: function () {

        for (i = 0; i < cats.image.length; i++) {

            formattedCatNames = HTMLcatName.replace("%data%", cats.name[i]);
            var catNames = formattedCatNames;

            formattedCatImages = HTMLcatImage.replace("%data%", cats.image[i]);
            var catImages = formattedCatImages;

            formattedCatCounter = HTMLcatCounter.replace("%data%", cats.clicks[i]);
            var catCounter = formattedCatCounter

            var elem = document.createElement('div');
            elem.innerHTML = catNames + catImages + catCounter;

            elem.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', (function(catCountUp) {
                return function() {
                    cats.clicks[catCountUp]++;
                    update();
            };
        })(i));
            document.body.appendChild(elem);
        }
    },
}

cats.display();

var getCounterClass = document.getElementsByClassName("counter");

var update = function() {

    for (j = 0; j < getCounterClass.length; j++) {
        getCounterClass[j].innerHTML = '<p class="counter">Number of clicks: ' + cats.clicks[j] + '</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see the click event, but this can be the error:

```
 getTags.innerHTML = '<p class="counter">Number of clicks: ' + cats.clicks[j] + '</p>';
```

replace with

```
getTags[j].innerHTML = 'Number of clicks: ' + cats.clicks[j];
```

you are missing the counter in the for loop for targeting the right element

Comment: ah that did not do it unfortunately. I updated the code in the OP.

Comment: great news. happy to help, some times two eyes more can find the small invisible problem